# python module empty after import

Tags: python, python-import

i noticed some seemingly strange behaviour when trying to import a python module named rmod2 in different ways.  if i start python from the directory where the *rmod2.py* file is located, it works fine. however, if i move the file to another folder where other modules are locate, it doesn't work as expected anymore.
the module/package folder is */usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7* and it is also contained in the *sys.path*.  so i've created the folder */usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rmod2* and put an empty *__init__.py* and the *rmod2.py* in there.  if i don't have the *__init__.py* i get:

```
>>> import rmod2
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rmod2
```

with the *__init__.py* file, the import seems to work, but the package is empty:

```
>>> import rmod2
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'rmod2']
>>> dir(rmod2)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>> rmod2.__path__
['/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rmod2']
>>> rmod2.__file__
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rmod2/__init__.py'
```

can someone tell me what's going on, and how to fix it to actually load the module contents when importing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the path to the directory your modules are located in to your [`sys.path` variable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) instead, *or* add the `rmod.py` module *directly* to a directory on the path (and not in a subdirectory).

By adding `__init__.py` to a directory, you converted it into a python package instead, making it an importable. If that was your intention, then you moved `rmod`-the-module inside of a `rmod`-the-package, and you can import that through that namespace:

```
from rmod2 import rmod2
```

Comment: placing the *.py* file in the top-level module directory seems to have done the trick. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once it happened to me that a package's modules weren't accesssible from package, but when imported directly, it worked. Probably missing `__all__` in package's `__init__.py`

This didn't work:

import mypkg
    obj = mypkg.mymodule.MyClass()

This worked:

```
import mypkg.mymodule
obj = mypkg.mymodule.MyClass()
```